# Apply custom theme to a SciChartSurface in SciChart Android

Tags: java, android, themes, scichart

Say I've created a theme like [this](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-chart-example-create-a-custom-theme/). I've named it `ChartTheme_Normal`. I apply it to a `ThemeManager` object like this:

```java
ThemeManager themeManager = new ThemeManager();
themeManager.addTheme(this, R.style.ChartTheme_Normal);
```

At that point, how do I go from there to adding it to the `SciChartSurface` I have?

`SciChartSurface` has a `applyThemeProvider(IThemeProvider)` method, but it requires an `IThemeProvider` and it looked like you could avoid using that if you made the theme in `styles.xml` and used `ThemeManager`.

If my understanding of themes in SciChart is completely off, please correct it if you're able to. I'm not familiar with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add theme into ThemeManager. You just need to declare new theme in styles.xml and apply it to SciChartSurface instance by calling [setTheme()](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~com.scichart.charting.visuals.SciChartSurface~setTheme.html):

```
// set theme id from styles
surface.setTheme(R.style.SciChart_BerryBlue);
```

That's all you need to do to apply new theme in SciChart Android

Comment: I did see the `setTheme` method for `SciChartSurface` but when I tried using it my IDE (Android Studio) wasn't recognizing it as a valid method. Do I need to update the version I'm using?

Comment: Oh, wait! I was using `ISciChartSurface`. I switched it over to `SciChartSurface` and it's all good. I'll try it out. If you're able to can you explain the difference between the classes with the I prefix and those without?

Comment: The difference is that [ISciChartSurface](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~com.scichart.charting.visuals.ISciChartSurface.html) is just an interface which defines some chart methods and it is implemented by [SciChartSurface](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~com.scichart.charting.visuals.SciChartSurface.html) class which represents actual chart.

Comment: Ah, that makes complete sense. So, you'd use the interface to make your own SciChartSurface-type class.